# How can order an List<Map<String, Object>> with PagedListHolder?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an PagedListHolder:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = n value; 
PagedListHolder pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder(list);
String sortColumn = request.getParameter("sidx");
String sord=request.getParameter("sord");
boolean ascending=false;
if(sord!=null&&sord.equals("asc")){
    ascending=true;
}
pagedListHolder.setSort(new MutableSortDefinition(sortColumn, ascending,true));
pagedListHolder.resort();
```

the sordColumn and sord are correct 
 
but not work how can solve? 
 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>();
```

Comment: i have try but not work:List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>();
  list = datavalue;
  PagedListHolder pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder(list);